# Linter for consistent indentation in HTML files

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, command-line-interface

I'm looking for a CLI tool, npm package or gulp/grunt plugin to validate proper indentation in HTML files.

All the options that I've tried don't report an error if the file is using the right spaces or tabs settings but the number of spaces expected is wrong.

For example, the following indentation won't be reported as wrong:

```html
<button>
      <span class="someting">Lorem ipsum</span>
  <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
            <span>Consectetuer</span>
            </button>
```

Ironically, the Stack Overflow editor detects wrong indentation, so I've been forced to use a snippet.

I've tried htmllint, lintspaces and htmlhint.

Comment: Questions asking for recommendations for tools are considered '[**off-topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)'. Please refer to the StackOverflow help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and the documentation for topics that are considered '[**on-topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)'.

Comment: I'm not asking for recommendations. I'm looking for a tool that detects wrong indentation because I haven't found any.

Comment: This is a top question... idk the answer. This is what stackoverflow is for @Obsidian Age and this is not offtopic...